# Can IronPython dynamically add methods to a C# class?

Tags: c#, delegates, ironpython

I have some simple C# types that are used in an embedded IronPython script:

```
//simple type
public class Foo
{
  public int a;
  public int b;
}

var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.foo = new Foo{ a = 1, b = 2 };

engine.Execute( "print( foo.a )", scope );
```

I'd like to add some functionality to `Foo` but I cannot modify it's code. Also I'd rather not derive from it nor use extension methods, but use delegates instead. Ideally I'd like to write something like

```
scope.AddMemberFunction( scope.foo, "Fun",
  new Func<Foo,int>( f => return f.a + f.b ) );
```

and then use it in the Python script directly:

```
print( foo.Fun() )
```

I thought this was exactly what could be done using the `Operations` but this raises an exception saying *'Foo' object has no attribute 'Fun'*

```
engine.Operations.SetMember( scope.foo, "Fun",
  new Func<Foo, int>( f => f.a + f.b ) );
```

Next I tried the Python way of things (say Foo is in a namespace IronPythonApp that is in and it's assembly is added to the engine.Runtime):

```
import IronPythonApp

def Fun( self ):
  return self.a + self.b

IronPythonApp.Foo.Fun = Fun
```

but this gives a similar exception: *can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'Foo'*

Is there a way to modify the Python class definition that ironPython internally generates?

**Update**

I explored some of the options as by Jeff Hardy's answer. Here are two ways that can both be made pretty scalable (just showing the straightforward way here)

*ExpandoObject!*

```
var foo = new Foo { a = 1, b = 2 };
dynamic exp = new ExpandoObject();
exp.Fun = new Func<int>( () => foo.a + foo.b );
exp.a = foo.a; //automating these is not a big deal
exp.b = foo.b; //

//now just add exp to the scope and done.
```

*Using SetMember after all*

```
scope.origFoo = new Foo { a = 1, b = 2 };

  //the only variable thing in this string is 'origFoo'
  //so it's no big deal scaling this
engine.Execute( @"
  class GenericWrapper( object ) :
    def __init__( self, foo ):
    self.foo = foo

  def __getattr__( self, name ) :
    return getattr( self.foo, name )

  foo = GenericWrapper( origFoo )", scope );

   //ha, now scope contains something that we can mess with after all
engine.Operations.SetMember( scope.foo, "Fun",
  new Func<int>( () => scope.foo.a + scope.foo.b ) );

engine.Execute( "print( foo.Fun() )", scope );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: nope, you can't modify a .NET class. By default, they don't have the necessary dynamic hooks to add members.

Your best bet is to wrap the class and add the members you want; Python makes this easy:

```
class FooWrapper(object):
  def __init__(self, foo):
    self.foo = foo

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.foo, name)

  def mymethod(self):
    ...
```

The [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) special method is only called for attributes that are not part of normal attribute lookup, so `mymethod()` will be looked up normally but anything else will be forwarded to the underlying object.

If you need to do it on the C# side, you can achieve the same thing by subclassing [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) and overloading the `Try*Member` functions.

Comment: +1 tried both ways and they work, though it's quite some work to make it generic and useful in production I guess